# Webdriver.io gets an HTML response from selenium when trying to create a new session

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver-io

I am trying to run my selenium tests using webdriver.io but it seems the test runner fails when trying to create the session:

```
[18:12:36]  COMMAND     POST     "/session"
[18:12:36]  DATA                {"desiredCapabilities": .... }
```

What follows is the response which is some default HTML page which selenium redirects to. When trying to create a session from the selenium console in the browser it works - and it seems the request is posted to **localhost:4444/wd/hub/session**.

I get the same result when running selenium-standalone-server by myself in the background and when running it via the webdriver.io selenium-standalone-service.

Answer (score 0):

I updated **selenium-standalone** and **webdriver.io** packages to the lastest version and ran the wdio configuration tool again which fixed the issue and i could see in the logs that the POST request is directed at **/wd/hub/session** and not **/session** as before.